# Calculated Field formula for triggering the task 15 minutes before the starting time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, date-time

I need to use a calculated field in order to trigger before 15mins of the task starting time. Please let me know what is the formula that I can use for this.

Is it something like below? 
=[Start Time]-15mm